# Ubuntu - Get information about shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, logging

Today one of my Ubuntu servers shut down unexpectedly. Now I'd like to analyse what caused the shutdown. Where can I look to get information on the cause  of the shutdown? I looked in `/var/log/*` but couldn't find any helpful information about what may have caused the shutdown or even the exact time of the shutdown. Where should I look?

**Edit**: I was able to find out that a power outage occurred. Is there a way to see the exact time? My guess is no, but maybe I'm wrong.